# Close an Excel file if it is found already open

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, exception

In the following code i am trying to check if an Excel file is open ,
if it is then I want to close it , when i run the code , the file does
not get closed , can you please help?

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Text;
> using System.IO;
> using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
> using System.Windows.Forms;
> using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
> using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
>
> namespace CloseIfFileOpen
> {
>     class Program
>     {
>         public static void Main()
>         {
>             Excel.Application oApp;
>             Excel.Workbook oBook;
>
>             oApp = new Excel.Application();
>
>             oBook =oApp.Workbooks.Add(@"C:\Users\user\Documents\WEF\Excel\Example.xlsx");
>
>
>             string filePath;
>
>             filePath = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\WEF\Excel\Example.xlsx";
>
>
>             try
>             {
>                 using (File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open)) { }
>             }
>             catch (IOException e)
>             {
>                 var errorCode = Marshal.GetHRForException(e) & ((1 << 16) - 1);
>
>                 //return errorCode == 32 || errorCode == 33;
>                 MessageBox.Show("the file is unavailable now");
>
>                 oBook.Save();
>                 oBook.Close();
>                 oApp.Quit();
>             }
>         }
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: I'd like to help, but your code is rather unreadable. Naming is horrible, no comments, and messy.

Answer (score 1):

Am I right in assuming that you want to check if the file is in use by another process, and if so, close it? Because I don't think there's any way to do that in windows, you can only close your own usage of the file. There could possibly be ways to force unlocking of files by use of the Win32 API, but nothing build into C#. Calling close on a file will only close your own usage of the file, it doesn't affect other processes.

Comment: You can kill specific processes within C#:

try
{
 foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("utorrent"))
            {
                proc.Kill();
            }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

Comment: Sure, but that forces you to kill the actual offending process instead of forcing it to release the file. It also assumes you know which the offending process is.

Comment: Yes exactly , In case the file is open then I would like to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method to check if i can open a file if yes, then do so, if not then don't
With the paramater Path set to the excel sheet path

```
    private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application appExcel;
    private Workbook newWorkbook = null;
    private _Worksheet objsheet = null;

    public void excel_init(String path)
    {
        appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            // then go and load this into excel
            newWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(path, true, true);
            objsheet = (_Worksheet)appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to open workbook");
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel);
            appExcel = null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not saying that you want exclusive access to the file. Seems unlikely, but perhaps Excel doesn't lock the file so that other processes can open the file in read mode. Maybe your file open line should be:

`using (File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)) { }`

Answer (score 0):

This code, for sure, will help you check either file is open or not
(i checked this code for excel file)

```
private bool check_file_oppen(string check)
    {//where string check is the path of required file

        try
        {
            Stream s = File.Open(check, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
            s.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("FILE IS NOT OPEN");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FILE IS OPEN");

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now , "if this excel file is open then how to close it?" is question i am still searching for,............

if you find answer, do share with me,...............

THANKS.

ARK.

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL"))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use this approach-

```
//Open the excel file using Desktop.getDesktop()
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new 
    File("C:\\Users\\AnubhavPatel\\Desktop\\Testing_Code_Macro.xlsm"));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
//Save and close it using robot class
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

    Thread.sleep(5000);

//Then write to it using outputStream   
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
            "C://Users//AnubhavPatel//Desktop/Testing_Code_Macro.xlsm");
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
```